# Undefined vs Empty String - Javascript with example

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the first `processed === true` and return the `value`.

My works seems to work but if there are no `processed` the **code turns `undefined` instead of `<empty string>`**

```js
const values = [{
    value: "bar",
    process: false
  },
  {
    value: "foo",
    process: false
  }
];

const myValue = values.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.primary) {
    return curr.value.toLowerCase();
  }
}, '');

console.log("My Value: " + myValue);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you should return acc which will assign to myValue .

Comment: do you need to add an 'else'?

Comment: What's `curr.primary`? Do you mean `curr.process`?

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` calls the callback function once for each item in the loop.

`curr` is the current value. `acc` is the return value from the previous function (or the second argument (`''`) the first time going around the loop.

Your code **completely ignores `acc`** so the value returned by `reduce` depends *entirely* on the last value in the array.

Your function tests that value with `curr.primary`. If that is a true value it `return curr.value.toLowerCase()`. If it isn't a true value, then it gets to the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement. Any function that doesn't `return` will return `undefined`.

---

To find the first value that matches a condition, use `find` not `reduce`.

Then do a test to use an empty string if you didn't find anything.

```
const match = values.find(value => value.primary === true);
const myValue = match?.value.toLowerCase() ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find the first `processed === true` and return the `value` [else an empty string `""`].

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) along with the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) in the case that no value is found:

```js
const array1 = [
  { value: 'bar', processed: false },
  { value: 'foo', processed: false },
];

const myValue1 = array1.find(o => o.processed)?.value.toLowerCase() ?? '';

console.log('myValue1:', myValue1); // "myValue1:" ""
console.log('type:', typeof myValue1); // "type:" "string"

const array2 = [
  { value: 'BAR', processed: false },
  { value: 'FOO', processed: true },
];

const myValue2 = array2.find(o => o.processed)?.value.toLowerCase() ?? '';

console.log('myValue2:', myValue2); // "myValue2:" "foo"
console.log('type:', typeof myValue2); // "type:" "string"
```

Here's a breakdown of the syntax evaluation for the first value:

```js
const myValue1 = array1.find(o => o.processed)?.value.toLowerCase() ?? '';
//               11111111111111111111111111111 22222222222222222222 44 55
//               33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
// 1. This evaluates to undefined
// 2. So this part is not evaluated, and...
// 3. the entire left side evaluates to undefined
// 4. Because 3 is nullable (null or undefined), when the ?? operator executes...
// 5. the left side (3) is ignored, and the right side (5) becomes the value
```

In contrast with the value computed from the second array:

```js
const myValue2 = array2.find(o => o.processed)?.value.toLowerCase() ?? '';
//               11111111111111111111111111111 22222233333333333333 55 66
//               44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
// 1. This evaluates to { value: 'FOO', processed: true }
// 2. So this part is evaluated to "FOO"
// 3. which becomes "foo", and...
// 4. the entire left side evaluates to "foo"
// 5. Because 4 is NOT nullable (null or undefined), when the ?? operator executes...
// 6. the left side (4) becomes the final value, and the right side (6) is ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the first element that meets a condition you should use [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).
Reduce will run on the entire array even after that condition is met since it's purpose is to *reduce* an entire array into a different data structure (i.e string/object). Find method will exit as soon as an item that meets the condition is found (or after checking the entire array if non of the items does)

As to replacing `undefined` with an empty string, in the attached snippet I used a [or condition](https://salferrarello.com/javascript-or-versus-nullish-coalescing-operator/) (although some would prefer [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)), since `undefined` is [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), it will insert the empty string.

```js
const values = [{
    value: "bar",
    process: false
  },
  {
    value: "foo",
    process: false
  }
];

const myValue = values.find(curr => curr.process);

console.log("My Value: " + (myValue?.value?.toLowerCase() || ''));
```

Best of luck with your project:)

Answer (score -1):

This should be all:

```js
const values = [{
    value: "bar",
    process: false
  },
  {
    value: "foo",
    process: false
  }
];

const myValue = values.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.process ? curr.value.toLowerCase() : '', '');

console.log("My Value: " + myValue);
```

Comment: This still has the problem the original code does: It only cares about the last item in the array, not the first where `process` is true.

Comment: Hmm... Well, even if the OP needed to use `reduce`, the callback was still wrong. So I corrected that.

Comment: You didn't correct it though, it still doesn't do what the OP is asking for. You changed it so it is broken in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

you might be better off using a foreach loop to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```js
    const values = [{
      value: "bar",
      process: false
    },
    {
      value: "foo",
      process: false
    }
  ];
  
  var processedValue = '';
  values.forEach(element => {
    if(element.process && !processedValue)
    processedValue = element.value;
  });
  
  console.log(processedValue);
```